# Meta-analysis for case control studies

Tags: meta-analysis, effect-size, case-control-study

I am working on a method of meta-analysis for case-control studies by stratifying cases and controls then calculating the effect size.

Can I do a meta-analysis including only case-control studies for the sake of experimenting the method?

Comment: Can you expand on why you think this would not work?

Comment: I mean not including cohort studies, for example, wouldn't be like excluding half the body of evidence? since I am experimenting the method only on case-control studies.

Comment: I think you can meta-analyze both study types as subgroups, and then see if they are consistent. You can do this with mvmeta or metafor in R.

Comment: @Joe_74 Thanks! that was very helpful, I will try it out.